# Cannot understand why this java do while loop is not working

Tags: java

```
 do
 {
  ch = (char)System.in.read();
  System.out.print(ch);
 }while(ch != '\n');
```

I thought this loop would repeat until I enter a new line? Not sure what I am doing wrong since it terminates after I input one character.

Comment: after in.read() it automatically a \n' happens. when you hit enter

Comment: This could have easily been solved by debugging, or even looking carefully at the output.

Answer (score 0):

After you input the first character, while loop condition would succeed and it waits for input from the user inside do-while. if you press `enter` its a new line character now in which case the while condition fails. in short your code is working as expected.

**Test:**

```
aa(if you press enter  key now)
while condition failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program works, but your loop doesn't really **start** before you press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

The `System.in.read` blocks until a newline is entered at the console. So, if you press the keys <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>\n</kbd>, program will halt on the `System.in.read()`-line , untill you press the <kbd>enter</kbd> (`\n`).

When <kbd>enter</kbd> is pressed, your program will kick in and echo back the line to the user.

The cause of this is how your console is configured. Normally, the terminal is in "cooked" mode, which alows you to use backspace and edit characters you type in. You should also be able to set the console in "raw" mode (line editing bypassed and no enter key required). This will probably produce the result you're after. On UNIX systems, the 'stty' command can change modes.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

**while(ch != 13);**

13 is the ASCI value of **enter**